# Problemas com site fullpage

Tags: bootstrap-3, fullpage.js

Estou com o seguinte problema estou desenvolvendo um site que usa um plugin chamado [jquery full page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) e Bootstrap na versão desktop ele funciona normalmente porém na versão mobile está todo "Bugado" é como se não reconhecesse os `grids` do Bootstrap veja o site [aqui](http://agenciafront.com.br/jetwash/).
Alguém poderia me ajudar não sei se existe algum tipo de conflito entre esses *frameworks* segue um trecho do código `html` do site:

HTML:

```html
{{--Menu--}}
<div id="right-menu" class="text-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <div class="vertical"></div>
    <ul id="menu" class="list-unstyled">
        <li data-menuanchor="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="services"><a href="#services">Serviços</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="about"><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="franchise"><a href="#franchise">Franquia</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="contact"><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="fullpage">
    {{--Home--}}
    <section class="section home" data-anchor="home">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class="list"><a href="#home" class="link">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="list"><a href="#services" class="link">Serviços</a></li>
                        <li class="list"><a href="#about" class="link">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li class="list"><a href="#franchise" class="link">Franquia</a></li>
                        <li class="list"><a href="#contact" class="link">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-left">
                <div class="col-md-6 home-info">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/jetwash-logo.png') }}" class="img-responsive logo" alt="jetwash">
                    <span class="subtitle">Tudo para seu carro</span>
                    <ul id="ticker" class="list-unstyled">
                        <li class="list">Limpeza Técnica de Motor</li>
                        <li class="list">Enceramento 3M</li>
                        <li class="list">Higienização</li>
                        <li class="list">Polimento 3M</li>
                        <li class="list">Película Anti-vandalismo 3M</li>
                        <li class="list">E muito mais confira</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="provide-services">
                        <h5 class="subtitle">Prestamos serviços em concessionárias e montadoras</h5>
                        <h5 class="subtitle">Fazemos preparação de veículos para comerciais, eventos e feiras.</h5>
                        <h3 class="title">Nossa equipe é treinada e certificada para realizar a manutenção dos carros, deixando os sempre limpos e        brilhando.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: defina "Bugado", acessei e para mim pareceu normal, algumas coisas parecem um pouco "pequenas" de mais no mobile, mas de resto nao parece nenhuma incompatibilidate

Comment: Sempre achei que isso seria OnePage!

Comment: cara se acessar num celualr ele por exemplo nao ativa o menu mobile e como se a tela desse um zoom out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema de responsividade ocorre por causa do plugin, ele limita sua tela para no minimo 980px, estava testando a versão mobile e quando tirei o plugin funcionou, daí plugin do autor  [Alvaro Trigo](https://github.com/alvarotrigo) precisa de limite de tela , caso queira fazer com responsividade precisará comprar a [extensão de responsividade](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/).

Encontrei esse outro plugin [aqui](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Create-Beautiful-Fullscreen-Scrolling-Websites-Using-switchPage-js.html), olhando o exemplo dele, funciona sem mexer na responsividade [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-Beautiful-Fullscreen-Scrolling-Websites-Using-switchPage-js/), talvez sirva pra vc.